# What is the difference between: proxy, port and server

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, proxy, server, port

What are the differences between a proxy, a port and a server. Also, what is the difference between local server and mysql sever and how we can differentiate among them ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ports: connection between 2 computers/interfaces or more using ports is more like a gate where the IP addresses pass.

Server: give different services for one client or more over the network.

Proxy: middle station between the server and the client.

Local: internal network or using loop interface, network card can be a server and also a client in the same time without going out side the network.

Mysql server is service for database, using default port 3306, it's have is own IP address and you can connect him depends on the firewall rules and routing.

Knowing this topics is not enough you need to cover all the network theory it's combine a lot of parts that only when you connecting all of them together you getting the entire picture....

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL